# Jinja2 Flask Python button across many pages

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Using flasks render template function, you can sculpt complicated pages quickly.
I want to have a small "up vote" "module" .html file that encases all the scripts and html needed to get the button working.

In jinja you can use the "extends to" tag that inserts the current section into the section called by the extend, but can you CALL a module from any template?

So a 1 to many relationship instead of a many to 1.

I could insert all the code for the button in the pages I want but I feel it would be better practice - and a lot faster - to have this small module encasing all the things I need. I could also make changes to this module alone which would be inherited by the entire project.

Sort of like a website embed.

I've thought of a couple of ways to do so, like parsing the info for the button into a variable for the render_template function, but which would you recommend doing?

Comment: You're probably looking for the [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) tag.

Comment: Thanks, I believe this is exactly what i needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [`include`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#include) statement. This is similar to using `import` in plain Python.

However, note that Jinja2 also has an `import` statement. This is different than `include` in that `import` is oriented towards using macros and executable code from a file; nothing is rendered. So, if you're separating common tasks that you do with Jinja2 statements, you can export those into macros in files that you then `import` in your templates.

However, when you want to include rendered output, which is what you're doing, stick to `include`.

Comment: Thanks, also for the extra info.